# NFC to Bluetooth converter

Tags: bluetooth, nfc

There is a medical device that collects data from body and stores it, and the stored data is updated every minute. It has only NFC to transmit the data.
 Data at any point can be retrived ONLY VIA NFC READER.

Is there any "nfc+bluetooth" reader/circuit available that can be attached to medical device, and it can switch on/off at fixed intervals like ,say every 5th minutere and read the data via nfc, and then send the data to smartphones via bluetooth. In short a nfc to bluetooth converter.

Please admins, dont delete this question if i am on a wrong forum or my question sounds irrelevant. It is very important. I am a doctor and have pretty less knowledge about technology. I wrote whatever best i could... Please let me get an answer to it.

Comment: exactly kianni.. we can read it by phone.. but bringing phone near the wearable device is not feasible. What i want is a NFC reading chip with memory to store the read data.. and a bluetooth on same module to transfer same data to smartphone

Comment: I understood you couldn't use NFC in your case, obviously... But as i said, your reader is already defined (i suppose you just bought it since you are a doctor) SO !!! how are you expecting to interact ON the reader ? Better ask yourself where the data is stored and then send it to your phone. Unless your reader has/can have a bluetooth interface (unlikely, for medical purpose) ? What reader are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

1/ This does what you are talking about. Relaying NFC data fron Freestyle Libre flash glucose monitoring device to a smartphone. It's a developed product though, not a chip.
https://miaomiao.eu/product/miaomiao-freestyle-libre-reader/

2/ There's also a device called BlueReader which does similar things.

3/ Abbott are about to release a new version of the Freestyle Libre with bluetooth built-in.

Answer (score -2):

NFC is the "secure" (depending on the reader and the readed technology and the ability of the user to set it up securely) communication between, here, the chip in the body and the medical device.

Also, there is a software behind this medical device that "manage" the data and store it in a database or something. Bluetooth has to be managed from this software.

Or what about another machine requesting the data recursively and then take care of bluetooth ?

Depending of the range of the **communication**, you could also use your phone to read it directly. But if it is NFC technically said -- which is probably the case since the data is quite 'sensitive'--, you won't have the range (NFC being **Near-Field** communication).